# chart.js not accepting data in dataset which stored in local storage

Tags: chart.js, angular7

Actually I'm trying for getting data from local storage and I get it and store in one variable call "dataValues".

That variable I'm passed to data in dataset(you can see in code).In that variable values are coming from local storage as I see it using alert in Angular 7.

But that values not shown on chart (Currently I'm using Chart.js) and also its not showing any error on console for same.

So why that is happing for it. Can anybody help me for that?

As you can see in code their is one "timeLabel" variable which also getting value from local storage and it accepted by chart but it not accepted for "dataValues".....

Please help me throught, Waiting for reply.

```
this.LineChart = new Chart('linechart', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: timeLabel,
        datasets: [{
          label: d.name,
          data: dataValues,
          fill: true,
          lineTension: 1,
          borderColor: 'blue',
          borderWidth: 1,
          pointBorderColor: 'red',
          pointBackgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved. I put min and max value for y axis correctly. So get my graph.

I put whole for this....Those who get same issue i hope it helps.

``````
            stacked:true,
            ticks:{
             min:scaleValY,   //scaleValY is value coming from my storage and it updated 
                             // as per keyword.
             max:scaleValY2,//scaleValY2 is value coming from my storage and it updated 
                           //as per keyword. 
              //suggestedMax:100
            }`````
``````